# Does your steed stay invisible after you dismount?

Tags: dnd-5e, invisibility, mounted-combat

So in the D&D game that I run, one of my players is a lore bard that took *find steed* as his magical secret. We just had a battle where he used *greater invisibility* while on his steed causing them both to be invisible.
Cool, all's well.
But he then dismounts and leaves to fight elsewhere and claims the steed should still have the greater invisibility on it.  I let it go for the time but it's been bothering me.  Any idea's if this is how the RAW is?

I know it's my choice as a DM but the player gets upset with "house rules" and I want it to be as fair as possible

Comment: How long is he leaving it alone? Doesn't Greater Invisibility only last a minute?

Comment: rulings are not house rules; you are the DM.  Is your question about whether or not you can make a ruling, or how the spell works?  You seem to have two different problems that you are trying to solve.

Comment: He is only using it during a combat so he is keeping to the spells time limit.

Comment: Also yes, I was just wondering if that was the actual RAW or he was abusing the ability

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, the spell continues on both creatures after dismounting

The relevant text from *Find Steed* is:

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

The spell doesn't say anything about needing to remain mounted in order to maintain this benefit. You only need to be mounted at the time you cast the spell in order to target both yourself and the mount. After that, the spell works as it normally would for both targets, regardless of whether or not you dismount.